# Database Design - Best way to show available hours?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am interested in seeing suggestions for a database design regarding business hours.

It would be quite similar to what Facebook has - [alt text http://uploader.ws/upload/200903/widget.png](http://uploader.ws/upload/200903/widget.png)

I have a list of businesses, and I would like for users to be able to input multiple sets of available hours for that business. e.g.,

Monday: open 9-5; Tuesday: open 9-12; 1-5; etc. I would not like to be limited to two sets of hours per day. Ideally, N sets of hours per day. If that's not practical, no more than 4... no less than 2.

I am interested in the "best" (theoretical) and the most practical solutions.

The DBMS I'm using is MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
create table business (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table open_hour_range (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  business_id int,
  day_of_week tinyint, /* 0-6 */
  open_time time,
  close_time time,
  foreign key(business_id) references business(id)
);
```

This allows you any combination of hours, including multiple per day.  However, it may be a bit slow from a querying perspective, in that you'll need to do a fair amount of joining to come up with the list of what hours a business is open.

Also, if you want to be able to display hours in a format like:

M-F 9-5
Sa-Su 9-12

You'd need to merge similar ranges in code, outside the database. If you wanted this sort merging, you could change day_of_week to a start_day and an end_day.

Comment: This is similar to what I was going to post.  I wouldn't consider the joins an issue however... I would do a single separate query to select all the applicable hour ranges for a business, and let the app code handle the formatting.  You can always cache the output as well.

Comment: What is the benefit of the open_hour_range.id column?

Comment: The open_hour_range.id column gives a way to uniquely identify a particular open_hour_range for updating/deletion.  This may be a bad habit - I guess you could make the full column set of the table be the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

A minor tweak to Scotty Allen's model:

business table:
  id - int
  business_name - string
open_hour_range table:
  id - int
  business_id - int //foreign key to business
  days_of_week- int // (bitmask) 1-127
  open_time - time
  close_time - time

Comment: Ooh, I like the bitmask idea - clever:)

Answer (score 0):

With **[Microsoft SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/)** database you could store that data as **typed XML** and still be able to sort and serach data based on one or more values in that field. Make any calculations if needed etc.

A value in that column could look similar to this:

```
<businessDays>
    <monday>
        <hours from="12" to="15" />
        <hours from="16" to="21" />
    </monday>
    <friday>
        <hours from="13" to="15" />
        <hours from="16" to="18" />
        <hours from="19" to="21" />
    </friday>
</businessDays>
```

References on **Typed XML**:

- [Typed XML in SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/denisruc/)
- [Typed XML Compared to Untyped XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx)

References on **indexing and quering XML data** in SQL Server:

- [XML Queries and Indexing in SQL Server 2005](http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3565996)
- [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML-DML - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050803.htm)

In your application you could **serialize/deserialize** this data into and from business objects.

Extremely simple and efficient.

Comment: Why would that be an advantage?

Comment: Only 1 column is used for storing this unstractured data. In the application you can deserialize it into business entity by using existing serialization/deserialization features of .NET. If you split that data into several columns or even tables like other guys suggest -> result is "overnormilized"

Comment: Sorry, I tagged the question as MySQL but I didn't specify that as a requirement in the question. Updating the question.

Comment: What if you want to find all businesses open 24 hours a day or something of that nature? You sort of limit the entire point of a database with this type of structure.

Comment: @d03boy, it's not a problem. You still will be able to index and query that data. Check out the references I specified.

Answer (score 0):

I wolud rather use datetime in columns `open_time` and `close_time`. Its for meetings that will start at night and will end in the morning next day. :)